# How to integrate PayPal express checkout with shipping detail?

Tags: php, payment-gateway, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using PayPal express checkout NVP API for my payment solution but for my product there is no shipping address need because its digitalis  good.

Any one please help me how to integrate for digital good payment solution.

query string

```
$nvpstr="&NOSHIPPING=1&L_NAME0=".$L_NAME0."&L_NAME1=".$L_NAME1."&L_AMT0=".$L_AMT0."&L_AMT1=".$L_AMT1."&L_QTY0=".$L_QTY0."&L_QTY1=".$L_QTY1."&MAXAMT=".(string)$maxamt."&AMT=".(string)$amt."&ITEMAMT=".(string)$itemamt."&CALLBACKTIMEOUT=4&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT1=8.00&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONlABEL1=UPS Next Day Air&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME1=UPS Air&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT1=true&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT0=3.00&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL0=UPS Ground 7 Days&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME0=Ground&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT0=false&INSURANCEAMT=1.00&INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED=true&CALLBACK=https://www.ppcallback.com/callback.pl&SHIPPINGAMT=8.00&SHIPDISCAMT=-3.00&TAXAMT=2.00&L_NUMBER0=1000&L_DESC0=Size: 8.8-oz&L_NUMBER1=10001&L_DESC1=Size: Two 24-piece boxes&L_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE1=0.5&L_ITEMWEIGHTUNIT1=lbs&ReturnUrl=".$returnURL."&CANCELURL=".$cancelURL ."&CURRENCYCODE=".$currencyCodeType."&PAYMENTACTION=".$paymentType;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To suppress the display of the buyer’s shipping address, set the NOSHIPPING parameter to 1 in the call to SetExpressCheckout. No shipping address displays on the PayPal pages whatsoever.

See this page for more details.
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECCustomizing

Comment: i have add NOSHIPPING in my query string still I am getting shipping address.... and i have updated the query string in my question

Comment: why does your query string start with & instead of ?.  Something is not going through to paypal, as that is exactly the way you suppress the shipping address as indicated by the link I posted.